# Cannot track mouse events OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, mouseevent, mouse

I am unable to track mouse events using the Highgui library of OpenCV. 
I want to print the position of the clicked points on my image but the onMouse() function tracks the clicks on the grey image that appears behind the actual image.

Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
// called when mouse is clicked
void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int f, void* userdata) {

    // If the left button is pressed
    if (event == cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){
        cout << "Position: "<< x <<", "<<y<< endl;
        return;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    // read image into cv::Mat input_img and visualize
    Mat image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if (!image.data)                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    String win_name= "window";
    namedWindow(win_name, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
    imshow(win_name, image);
    setMouseCallback(win_name, onMouse, (void*)&image);
    cout << "setMouseCallBack CALLED" << endl;
    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: instead of waitKey(0) can you try an empty loop with while(waitKey(1) != 0){}?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean saying "appears", you have only one window, by the way, try to call function like this

```
setMouseCallback(win_name, onMouse, 0);
```

I guess maybe by passing pointer it takes only pointer to data and can't read information about image color.

Comment: I pass the pointer because I'll need it later in the function. I tried passing 0, but the problem persists. When I call imshow, 2 windows appear: one is totally grey, and the other contains my image. The windows share the same name.

Comment: are you using debug libraries in release build or vice versa?